# Django read_default_file doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I try to use read_defaul_file option but it doesn't work.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '/vagrant/project/my.cnf'
    }
}}
```

my.cnf

```
[client]
database=db_2
user=root
password=root
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I pass settings as usual It works normally. But It doesn't read my.cnf file. File has 777 permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             'OPTIONS': {
               'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my.cnf'),
             }
         }
     }
```

my.cnf

```
[client]
database = db_2
user = root
password = root
default-character-set = utf8
```

Have a look on it https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24653

Comment: What is even different about this?

Comment: Instead of passing static path you should pass Relative path.